# GCP Storage Authenticated Browser Downloads

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've been attempting to setup authenticated browser downloads for files within our GCS buckets, but cannot make this work. Users with READER ACL permissions always receive Forbidden/403.

The section on [Cookie-based authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#cookieauth), states this should work, as does this on [Authenticated Browser Downloads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration).

I tried creating a project level IAM entry for the user@domain.com with Storage Object Viewer and a Custom Role for the `storage.objects.get` permission.

Then tried directly setting the user@domain.com READ permission on the bucket and on the file directly, both via the Console and via:

```
gsutil acl ch -u user@domain.com:R gs://<bucket>
gsutil acl ch -u user@domain.com:R gs://<bucket>/file
```

I've also tried to set default ACLs.

I'm testing the downloads from a different browser (tried both Chrome and Safari).

When I request the `https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket>/file`, I am prompted to authenticate but always receive the Forbidden/403.

Is there a way to see where/why the permission is being denied ?
What am I missing ?

Comment: make sure you don't have Audit Log enabled: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#trouble-download-storage-cloud

Answer (score 1):

The below set up works for me.

```
Bucket Name: bb1
Object Name: test1.txt
Test Account: sample@gmail.com
```

1. IAM & Admin

   - Go to IAM and add "sample@gmail.com".
   - Give Role "Project->Viewer" to this new account.
2. Roles

   - Got to Roles and create a custom role "Sample Download Role".
   - Give permissions:
     storage.buckets.get
     storage.buckets.list
     storage.objects.get
     storage.objects.list
3. Bucket

   - Go to bucket bb1 and select "edit bucket permissions" from the menu next to your bucket.
   - You'll see that sample account it already added as "Viewer" with permissions inherited.
   - Add the sample account and assign the custom role we created above.
4. Test

   - In a new browser, logout of all google accounts and try the URL: https://storage.cloud.google.com/bb1/test1.txt
   - This is assuming the object is directly under the bucket.
   - You would be redirected to google page for login.
   - Make sure your previous security configurations for this google account do not clash with this new configuration.